# regular expression for matching different type of exception

Tags: regex, splunk

i've following exception to match in logs. These are few lines from log.

An Error has occured for com.marsh.csa.exception.**NoClientInfoFound**:

Remote Exception while updating CSA Details java.rmi.**ServerException**:

handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.**MarshException**:

Found Exception, class:java.lang.**NullPointerException**,

org.springframework.dao.**DataAccessResourceFailureException**

org.springframework.jdbc.**UncategorizedSQLException**

I'm able to match 4 of above 5 exceptions but unable to match this one

.csa.exception.**NoClientInfoFound**:

my regex :
(?i)[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.(?[a-zA-Z]+Exception)

how to match all 5 above exception?
i tried even like this

(?i)[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.(?[a-zA-Z]+(Exception|NoClientInfoFound))

still unable to match!!

EDIT:

added one more exception

org.springframework.jdbc.**UncategorizedSQLException**

and tried with 
(?i)\sa-z*(?P[a-z]+Exception|NoClientInfoFound|UncategorizedSQLException)

but its not matching **UncategorizedSQLException**

Comment: `(?[a-zA-Z]+(Exception|NoClientInfoFound))` would require something to be before NoClientInfoFound. `(?[a-zA-Z]+Exception|NoClientInfoFound)` is much better.

Comment: Thanks h2ooooooo. It worked !! :):)

Comment: But if it is not NoClientInfoFound name then how to match other names other than specifying directly the names

Comment: It depends what the other errors are?

Comment: Is my regex fine or it needs any improvements ?

Comment: If the line always ends with exception etc., why not just use `(Exception|NoClientInfoFound)$`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to allow longer package names for exceptions:

```
(?i)[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+Exception
```

Note that using the case insensitive flag means you don't have to list both letter cases in the character class ranges.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, Thanks for suggestion. Can you tell me the significance of } in (\.[a-z]}+)* which you've suggested

Comment: @Pradi the significance is... a mistake! It was a typo :) I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Search from the end to the front by using the dollar sign, then the next item before it, and so on. This gets all the items at the end of each line you listed above. I used the "?" to tell it to do "either or".

```
 (?i)((UncategorizedSQLException|DataAccessResourceFailureException|NullPointerException|MarshException|ServerException|NoClientInfoFound).?)$
```

Here's the regex in action.
http://regexr.com?380gf